# Use mic from phone connected to USB

Tags: usb, android, microphone, phone

I have a Ubuntu machine and an android phone (it's a Nokia 6.1 running android 10).
My Ubuntu machine does not have a mic or bluetooth to connect my headset, but I thought that maybe it is possible to use my phones mic which I can connect through usb.
Does anyone have experience in the matter?
Thanks in advance to all.